# Fixing this piece of code to check constraints on a column in formload

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to add a check constraints on my form load in C# to avoid a specific name being added to a column. How can I fix this code?

```
try
{
    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=veronicas;  Integrated Security=True";
    con.Open();
    com.CommandText = "ALter Table [Veronicas].[Sales].[Customers] ADD Constraints FirstName check (FistName != Farzam )";
    com.Connection = con;
    MessageBox.Show(com.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using C# to alter your schema? Why not just run it as a script?

Comment: Why don't you want to make any sales to people called Farzam? Seems a bit arbitrary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any errors?

Without knowing the problem you're seeing it's very hard to suggest an answer... my guess would be that Farzam needs to be in single quotes

```
com.CommandText = "ALter Table [Veronicas]..[Sales].[Customers] ADD constraint FirstName check (FirstName != 'Farzam' )";
```

Comment: This is correct, and further to this, it's ADD CONSTRAINT and the column name 'FistName' is also spelled incorrectly.

Comment: Good spot - also shouldn't it by "add constraint" not "add constraints"? This is why error messages are so important!!!

Comment: Thanks @MattGriffiths  - assuming Veronicas is the DB shouldn't that be a double dot between that and sales?

Comment: Many thanksss , you are right i had spelling error. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @Parisan if this has solved your problem please mark it as the answer